# how to add and trigger dynamic urls in react-boostrap

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap for my application i am rendering one dropdown dynamically and adding dynamic links to that using `this` but it is giving me compiling error. please let me know ho to do this

```
export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            show: false,
            planingShow: false
        }
    }
    programDetails(pk){
        console.log("pk",pk)
    }
render(){
return  (
   <NavDropdown
                            eventKey={3}
                            title="Dropdown"
                            id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                            noCaret
                            bsClass="dropdown"
                            role="menuitem"
                            title="PROGRAM"

      >
                            {program.map((prog) => 
                              <MenuItem className="dropdown-program" key={prog.pk} onClick={this.programDetails.bind(this,{prog.pk})}>{prog.name}</MenuItem>   )}
)
}</NavDropdown>
```

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: `Unexpected token`

Comment: I've pasted that into an editor and there are loads of reasons that won't compile.  For a start the <NavDropdown> tag is never closed.  `{ prog.pk }` in the bind expression isn't a valid javascript object, and the onClick is missing a closing `}`

Comment: @MattWatson: my actual code only has problem `{prog.pk}` otherwise whole code is big and use it properly

Comment: @MattWatson: can u please let me know how to resolve second error `{prog.pk}`

Comment: I edited my code please see once

Comment: The second argument to `bind` should be a valid JavaScript object. `{prog.pk}` isn't a javascript object. Try using this link to create a valid object: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/